# Rotating two images joined together like an arm

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

im trying to rotate an arm, when i click on the upperarm it rotates 12 degrees. How do i also rotate the lower arm the same way so that its attached to the upper arm. i have set an offset in both images which is the point of rotation. Can anyone help.

I guess i need to transform both points of rotation by the same amount? any help would be great.

```
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>


      function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        for(var src in sources) {
          numImages++;
        }
        for(var src in sources) {
          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
              callback(images);
            }
          };
          images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
      }


      function initStage(images) {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: 'container',
          width: 1600,
          height: 1200
        });



        //body
        var bodyGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          draggable: false
        }); 

        //arm
        var armGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          draggable: false
        }); 


        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        /*
         * go ahead and add the groups
         * to the layer and the layer to the
         * stage so that the groups have knowledge
         * of its layer and stage
         */
        layer.add(bodyGroup);
        layer.add(armGroup);
        stage.add(layer);




        //**********************************************************
        //body image
        //bodyImg=createNewKineticImage(0,0,images.body);


        //**********************************************************
        //ARM       
        //START POINT
        //**********************************************************
        upperArmX=800;
        upperArmY=600;

        //**********************************************************
        //upperarm
        //**********************************************************
        var upperArmImg=createNewKineticImage(upperArmX,upperArmY,images.upperarm); 
        upperArmImg.offsetX(upperArmImg.width());
        upperArmImg.offsetY(upperArmImg.height()/2);
        //**********************************************************



        //**********************************************************
        //fore arm
        //**********************************************************
        var foreArmImg=createNewKineticImage(upperArmX,upperArmY,images.forearm);   
        foreArmImg.offsetX(foreArmImg.width()/2);
        foreArmImg.offsetY(foreArmImg.height());
        foreArmImg.x(foreArmImg.x()-upperArmImg.width());
        foreArmImg.rotate(-90);
        //**********************************************************


        //**********************************************************
        //hand arm
        //**********************************************************
        /*
        var handArmImg=createNewKineticImage(upperArmX,upperArmY,images.hand);  
        handArmImg.offsetX(handArmImg.width()/2);
        handArmImg.x(handArmImg.x()-(upperArmImg.width()+foreArmImg.height()));
        */
        //**********************************************************


        //groups
        //bodyGroup.add(bodyImg);

        //arm group
        armGroup.add(upperArmImg);
        armGroup.add(foreArmImg);   
        //armGroup.add(handArmImg);



        //EVENTS
        //**********************************************************
        //**********************************************************
        //allow dragged image to move to top layer
        bodyGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
          this.moveToTop();
        });



        //upper rotate
        upperArmImg.on('mousedown',function(evt) {
            console.log('down');
            //rotate
            this.rotateDeg(12);


            foreArmImg.rotate(12);



            stage.draw();
        });



        foreArmImg.on('mousedown',function(evt) {
            console.log('down');
            //rotate
            this.rotateDeg(-12);

            stage.draw();
        });


        /*
        //hand events       
        handArmImg.on('mousedown',function(evt) {
            console.log('down');
            //rotate
            this.rotateDeg(-12);



            stage.draw();
        });
        */



        //DEBUG 
        stage.on('mousemove',function(evt) {

            console.log("x, "+evt.x +" y " + evt.y);            
            //stage.draw();
        });


        /*
        var oldY;
        forearmImg.on('mousedown',function(evt) {

            //is y up or down           
            if(oldY==0)
                oldY=evt.y;       

            console.log("y "+evt.y);    
            console.log("oldy "+oldY);          

        }); 


        // for change events, get the old and new val       
        forearmImg.on('xChange', function(evt) {
          var oldVal = evt.oldVal;
          var newVal = evt.newVal;

          console.log("oldVal "+oldVal);
          console.log("newVal "+newVal);
        });
        */



        stage.draw();
      }





     //create a new kinectic image object
      function createNewKineticImage(x,y,imgObject)
      {
        var newImg = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          image: imgObject,
          name: 'image'
        })
        return newImg;
      }


    //create a new kinectic image object specifying the widht and height
      function createNewKineticImageWithSize(x,y,imgObject,w,h)
      {
        var newImg = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          image: imgObject,
          width: w,
          height: h,
          name: 'image'
        })
        return newImg;
      }

      function createNewKineticImageOffSet(x,y,imgObject,w,h,offX,offY)
      {
        var newImg = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          width: w,
          height: h,
          image: imgObject,
          name: 'image',
          offset: {x:offX, y:offY}
        })
        return newImg;
      }


      var sources = {
        body: 'teddybear_gfx/body.png',
        forearm: 'teddybear_gfx/forearm.png',
        upperarm: 'teddybear_gfx/lowerarm.png',
        hand: 'teddybear_gfx/hand.png'
      };        




      loadImages(sources, initStage);



    </script>
```

Working demo (couldnt get it to work with jsfiddle.

http://irishbloke.net/tmp/CA1v2_kinectic%20js.htm

Comment: Put your upper arm and fore-arm in a group and rotate the group with an offset at the shoulder joint. You don't need to rotate the fore-arm at all unless you want to "curl" the fore-arm towards the upper arm.

Comment: how do i set the offset for a group? 
group.setoffsetX(value);

Comment: You can do `group.offsetX(shoulderX);` and `group.offsetY(shoulderY)`